# float/double max binary decimal places

Tags: binary, decimal

How many binary decimal places can be precisely calculated when I use float or double?
I'm working on a project, where I have to get nearly exact numbers and do some calculation in binary. I've read an article which claimed 39 digits...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As per IEEE 754 standards, floats have 32 bits and are made up of 1 bit for the sign (+ or -), 8 bits for the exponents and 23 bits for the mantissa or fraction. This means that a floating point gets 23 bits for the decimal.

Doubles have 64 bits with 1 bit for sign, 8 bits for exponent, 55 bits for the decimal.

So doubles are more accurate but need more memory than floats.

Comment: Thank you very much. This means float can display 23 bits after the "decimal point"?

Comment: Yes, but some interpreters such as python may not follow these standards. So you may have to use a standard library such as `decimal`